# Not able to connect to network inside docker container

Tags: docker

I have a CentOS 7 host on which I am running Docker. When I do a ping from my host to 8.8.8.8, ping was successful whereas same inside a docker container is not working.

From Host

```
[root@linux1 ~]# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=31.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=31.6 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 31.592/31.617/31.643/0.179 ms
```

From Docker Container (I am using basic ubuntu image):

```
[root@linux1 ~]# docker run ubuntu ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.17.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.17.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.17.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.17.0.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 5000ms
pipe 4
```

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. It is not an issue with the DNS but an issue with the network connection itself inside Docker containers. Drilled down the issue is the default IP assigned to docker0 interface, which conflicted with my network address. Forced docker daemon to assign an IP so that it won't conflict and my issue is resolved.

Thanks

Comment: Hi i am facing a similar issue. Can you provide the command you used to force the docker daemon to assign it an IP.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I faced a similar network issue. The other answers here didn't help: DNS was working fine and restarting Docker wouldn't change a thing. I've found that specifying the network as `host` solved it.

There are three ways of doing it:

**In [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode):**

By setting `network_mode` in the `yaml` file:

```
services:
  worker:
    build: .
    network_mode: host
```

**In the [image building stage](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) for RUN commands:**

`docker build --network=host`

**In the [execution stage](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) for the application:**

`docker run --network=host <image>`

Comment: When I added `network_mode: host`, I got the following error: `ERROR: for semaphore  "host" network_mode is incompatible with port_bindings`.

Comment: @KelvinLow probably because you're using both host network and port mappings. Port mappings are not necessary in the host network, so either remove that, or use another network mode.

Answer (score 1):

**Restart the Docker daemon on Debian9**

`service docker restart`

and the connections and networks works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`docker run --dns=8.8.8.8 -it ubuntu ping 8.8.8.8`

Ref: [DOCKER DNS](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/articles/networking/#dns)

Comment: Tried that too and same result as without --dns.

Comment: docker run --dns=8.8.8.8 -it ubuntu ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.17.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

Comment: what is result of `route -n` after `docker run --dns=8.8.8.8 -it ubuntu`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when stop and start container separately. I have just rebuild and re up containers.

```
docker-compose down

docker-compose build

docker-compose up -d
```

And then problem gone.